# How can I calculate time elapsed in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, date

I print the start and end time using `date +"%T"`, which results in something like:

```
10:33:56
10:36:10
```

How could I calculate and print the difference between these two?

I would like to get something like:

```
2m 14s
```

Comment: On another note, could you not use the `time` command?

Comment: Use unix time instead, `date +%s` , then subtract to get the difference in seconds.

Answer (score 678, accepted):

Bash has a handy `SECONDS` builtin variable that tracks the number of seconds that have passed since the shell was started. This variable retains its properties when assigned to, and the value returned after the assignment is the number of seconds since the assignment plus the assigned value.

Thus, you can just set `SECONDS` to 0 before starting the timed event, simply read `SECONDS` after the event, and do the time arithmetic before displaying.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SECONDS=0
# do some work
duration=$SECONDS
echo "$((duration / 60)) minutes and $((duration % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```

As this solution doesn't depend on `date +%s` (which is a GNU extension), it's portable to all systems supported by Bash.

Documentation:

> SECONDS This variable expands to the number of seconds since the shell
> was started. Assignment to this variable resets the count to the value
> assigned, and the expanded value becomes the value assigned plus the
> number of seconds since the assignment. The number of seconds at shell
> invocation and the current time are always determined by querying the
> system clock. If SECONDS is unset, it loses its special properties,
> even if it is subsequently reset.  [https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html]

Comment: +1. Incidentally, you can trick `date` into performing the time arithmetic for you, by writing `date -u -d @"$diff" +'%-Mm %-Ss'`. (That interprets `$diff` as seconds-since-the-epoch, and computes the minutes and seconds in UTC.) That's probably not any more elegant, though, just better obfuscated. :-P

Comment: Nice and simple. If someone needs hours: `echo "$(($diff / 3600)) hours, $((($diff / 60) % 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."`

Comment: It should read `$(date -u +%s)` to prevent a race condition on dates where the daylight saving time is switched.  And beware of the evil leap seconds ;)

Comment: @Tino : almost four years after the original answer, I found out that using `date` here is not needed at all. Oh well...

Comment: @daniel-kamil-kozar  Nice find.  However this is a bit fragile.  There is only one such variable, so it cannot be used recursively to measure performance, and even worse, after `unset SECONDS` it is gone: `echo $SECONDS; unset SECONDS;  SECONDS=0; sleep 3; echo $SECONDS`

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question as asked. Hence, downvote.

Comment: @ParthianShot : I'm sorry that you think so. However, I believe that this answer is what most people need while searching for answers to a question like this one : to measure how much time passed between events, not to calculate time.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I disagree - I came here searching for how to calculate the difference between two times I'm reading from a logfile, and the related question asking that is marked as a duplicate of this.

Comment: You better store the value of SECONDS in another variable, in case the SECONDS is needed somewhere else.

Comment: Absolutely the simplest and smartest timer function for bash I've seen yet. Thank you so much.

Comment: `SECONDS` doesn't work in docker alpine.  This answer works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20249473/5401310

Comment: @saianudeep It doesn't work because Alpine doesn't have Bash by default, but the busybox-provided ash. This was a question asking about Bash and the answer obviously uses Bash-exclusive facilities. This is exactly why you should explicitly state Bash usage in your scripts' shebangs.

Answer (score 158):

#### Seconds

To measure elapsed time (in seconds) we need:

- an integer that represents the count of elapsed seconds and
- a way to convert such integer to an usable format.

---

##### An integer value of elapsed seconds:

- There are two Bash internal ways to find an integer value for the number of elapsed seconds:

1. Bash variable SECONDS (if SECONDS is unset it loses its special property).

   - Setting the value of SECONDS to 0:

     ```
           SECONDS=0
           sleep 1  # Process to execute
           elapsedseconds=$SECONDS
     ```
   - Storing the value of the variable `SECONDS` at the start:

     ```
           a=$SECONDS
           sleep 1  # Process to execute
           elapsedseconds=$(( SECONDS - a ))
     ```
2. Bash printf option `%(datefmt)T`:

   ```
        a="$(TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%s)T\n' '-1')"    ### `-1`  is the current time
        sleep 1                                  ### Process to execute
        elapsedseconds=$(( $(TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%s)T\n' '-1') - a ))
   ```

---

##### Convert such integer to an usable format

The bash internal `printf` can do that directly:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' 12345
03:25:45
```

similarly

```
$ elapsedseconds=$((12*60+34))
$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' "$elapsedseconds"
00:12:34
```

*but* this will fail for durations of more than 24 hours, as we actually print a wallclock time, not really a duration:

```
$ hours=30;mins=12;secs=24
$ elapsedseconds=$(( ((($hours*60)+$mins)*60)+$secs ))
$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' "$elapsedseconds"
06:12:24
```

For the lovers of detail, from [bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf):

> `%(FORMAT)T` outputs the date-time string resulting from using FORMAT
> as a format string for [`strftime(3)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/). The associated argument is the
> number of seconds since [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or -1 (current time) or -2 (shell
> startup time). If no corresponding argument is supplied, the current
> time is used as default.

So you may want to just call `textifyDuration $elpasedseconds` where `textifyDuration` is yet another implementation of duration printing:

```
textifyDuration() {
   local duration=$1
   local shiff=$duration
   local secs=$((shiff % 60));  shiff=$((shiff / 60));
   local mins=$((shiff % 60));  shiff=$((shiff / 60));
   local hours=$shiff
   local splur; if [ $secs  -eq 1 ]; then splur=''; else splur='s'; fi
   local mplur; if [ $mins  -eq 1 ]; then mplur=''; else mplur='s'; fi
   local hplur; if [ $hours -eq 1 ]; then hplur=''; else hplur='s'; fi
   if [[ $hours -gt 0 ]]; then
      txt="$hours hour$hplur, $mins minute$mplur, $secs second$splur"
   elif [[ $mins -gt 0 ]]; then
      txt="$mins minute$mplur, $secs second$splur"
   else
      txt="$secs second$splur"
   fi
   echo "$txt (from $duration seconds)"
}
```

---

#### GNU date

To get formatted time we should use an external tool (GNU date) in several ways to get up to almost a year length and including nanoseconds.

##### Math inside date.

There isn't any need for external arithmetic, do it all in one step inside `date`:

```
date -u -d "0 $FinalDate seconds - $StartDate seconds" +"%H:%M:%S"
```

Yes, there is a `0` zero in the command string. It is needed.

That's assuming you could change the `date +"%T"` command to a `date +"%s"` command so the values will be stored (printed) in seconds.

Note that the command is limited to:

- Positive values of `$StartDate` and `$FinalDate` seconds.
- The value in `$FinalDate` is bigger (later in time) than `$StartDate`.
- Time difference smaller than 24 hours.
- You accept an output format with Hours, Minutes and Seconds. Very easy to change.
- It is acceptable to use -u UTC times. To avoid "DST" and local time corrections.

---

If you **must** use the `10:33:56` string, well, just convert it to seconds. Also, the word *seconds* could be abbreviated as *sec*:

```
string1="10:33:56"
string2="10:36:10"
StartDate=$(date -u -d "$string1" +"%s")
FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$string2" +"%s")
date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S"
```

Note that the seconds time conversion (as presented above) is relative to the start of "this" day (Today).

---

The concept could be extended to nanoseconds, like this:

```
string1="10:33:56.5400022"
string2="10:36:10.8800056"
StartDate=$(date -u -d "$string1" +"%s.%N")
FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$string2" +"%s.%N")
date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S.%N"
```

---

If is required to calculate longer (up to 364 days) time differences, we must use the start of (some) year as reference and the format value `%j` (the day number in the year):

Similar to:

```
string1="+10 days 10:33:56.5400022"
string2="+35 days 10:36:10.8800056"
StartDate=$(date -u -d "2000/1/1 $string1" +"%s.%N")
FinalDate=$(date -u -d "2000/1/1 $string2" +"%s.%N")
date -u -d "2000/1/1 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%j days %H:%M:%S.%N"

Output:
026 days 00:02:14.340003400
```

Sadly, in this case, we need to manually subtract `1` ONE from the number of days.
The date command view the first day of the year as 1.
It is not that difficult...

```
a=( $(date -u -d "2000/1/1 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%j days %H:%M:%S.%N") )
a[0]=$((10#${a[0]}-1)); echo "${a[@]}"
```

The use of long number of seconds is valid and documented on *[21.1.7 Examples of date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html#Examples-of-date)*.

---

#### BusyBox date

A tool used in smaller devices (a very small executable to install): [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox).

Either make a link to BusyBox called date:

```
$ ln -s /bin/busybox date
```

Use it then by calling this `date` (place it in a PATH included directory).

Or make an alias like:

```
$ alias date='busybox date'
```

---

BusyBox date has a nice option: -D to receive the format of the input time.

That opens up a lot of formats to be used as time.
Using the -D option we can convert the time 10:33:56 directly:

```
date -D "%H:%M:%S" -d "10:33:56" +"%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S"
```

And as you can see from the output of the Command above, the day is assumed to be "today". To get the time starting on epoch:

```
$ string1="10:33:56"
$ date -u -D "%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S" -d "1970.01.01-$string1" +"%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S"
1970.01.01-10:33:56
```

BusyBox date can even receive the time (in the format above) without -D:

```
$ date -u -d "1970.01.01-$string1" +"%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S"
1970.01.01-10:33:56
```

And the output format could even be seconds since epoch.

```
$ date -u -d "1970.01.01-$string1" +"%s"
52436
```

For both times, and a little bash math (BusyBox can not do the math, yet):

```
string1="10:33:56"
string2="10:36:10"
t1=$(date -u -d "1970.01.01-$string1" +"%s")
t2=$(date -u -d "1970.01.01-$string2" +"%s")
echo $(( t2 - t1 ))
```

Or formatted:

```
$ date -u -D "%s" -d "$(( t2 - t1 ))" +"%H:%M:%S"
00:02:14
```

Comment: This is such an amazing answer covered a lot of bases and with fine explanations. Thank you!

Comment: I had to look up the `%(FORMAT)T` string passed to the `printf` command integrated in bash. From [bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf): _`%(FORMAT)T` output the date-time string resulting from using `FORMAT` as a format string for strftime(3). The associated argument is the number of seconds since Epoch, or -1 (current time) or -2 (shell startup time). If no corresponding argument is supplies, the current time is used as default_. That's esoteric. In this case, `%s` as given to `strftime(3)` is "the number of seconds since the epoch".

Answer (score 49):

Here is how I did it:

```
START=$(date +%s);
sleep 1; # Your stuff
END=$(date +%s);
echo $((END-START)) | awk '{print int($1/60)":"int($1%60)}'
```

It is really simple. Take the number of seconds at the start, take the number of seconds at the end, and print the difference in minutes:seconds.

Comment: How is that any different from my solution? I really can't see the benefit from calling `awk` in this case, since Bash handles integer arithmetic equally well.

Comment: Your answer is correct too. Some people, like me, prefer to work with awk than with bash inconsistencies.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more about the inconsistencies in Bash concerning integer arithmetic? I'd like to know more about this, since I wasn't aware of any.

Comment: I was just looking for this. I don't understand the criticism to this answer. I like to see more than one solution to a problem. And, I am one that prefers `awk` commands to bash (if for nothing else, because awk works in other shells). I liked this solution better. But that is my personal opinion.

Comment: Leading zeros:  echo $((END-START)) | awk '{printf "%02d:%02d\n",int($1/60), int($1%60)}'

Comment: Or with `printf`; hours, minutes, and seconds: `printf '%02dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $(($secs/3600)) $(($secs%3600/60)) $(($secs%60))`

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to use `datediff` from `dateutils` (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#datediff):

```
$ datediff 10:33:56 10:36:10
134s

$ datediff 10:33:56 10:36:10 -f%H:%M:%S
0:2:14

$ datediff 10:33:56 10:36:10 -f%0H:%0M:%0S
00:02:14
```

You could also use [Gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations). `mawk` 1.3.4 also has `strftime` and `mktime`, but older versions of `mawk` and `nawk` don't.

```
$ TZ=UTC0 awk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%T",mktime("1970 1 1 10 36 10")-mktime("1970 1 1 10 33 56"))}'

00:02:14
```

Or here's another way to do it with GNU `date`:

```
$ date -ud@$(($(date -ud'1970-01-01 10:36:10' +%s)-$(date -ud'1970-01-01 10:33:56' +%s))) +%T

00:02:14
```

Comment: I was looking for something like your GNU `date ` method. Genius.

Comment: Please delete my comment...sorry

Comment: After installing `dateutils` via apt, there was no `datediff` command - had to use `dateutils.ddiff`.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to propose another way that avoids recalling the `date` command. It may be helpful in case if you have already gathered timestamps in the `%T` date format:

```
ts_get_sec()
{
  read -r h m s <<< $(echo $1 | tr ':' ' ' )
  echo $(((h*60*60)+(m*60)+s))
}

start_ts=10:33:56
stop_ts=10:36:10

START=$(ts_get_sec $start_ts)
STOP=$(ts_get_sec $stop_ts)
DIFF=$((STOP-START))

echo "$((DIFF/60))m $((DIFF%60))s"
```

We can even handle milliseconds in the same way.

```
ts_get_msec()
{
  read -r h m s ms <<< $(echo $1 | tr '.:' ' ' )
  echo $(((h*60*60*1000)+(m*60*1000)+(s*1000)+ms))
}

start_ts=10:33:56.104
stop_ts=10:36:10.102

START=$(ts_get_msec $start_ts)
STOP=$(ts_get_msec $stop_ts)
DIFF=$((STOP-START))

min=$((DIFF/(60*1000)))
sec=$(((DIFF%(60*1000))/1000))
ms=$(((DIFF%(60*1000))%1000))

echo "${min}:${sec}.$ms"
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle millisecons, e.g. 10:33:56.104

Comment: Millisecond handling misbehaves if the millisecond field begins with a zero.  For instance ms="033" will give trailing digits of "027" because the ms field is being interpreted as octal.  changing "echo" ... "+ms))" to ... "+${ms##+(0)}))" will fix this as long as "shopt -s extglob" appears somewhere above this in the script.  One should probably strip leading zeroes from h, m, and s as well...

Comment: `echo $(((60*60*$((10#$h)))+(60*$((10#$m)))+$((10#$s))))` worked for me since I got `value too great for base (error token is "08")`

Answer (score 10):

Following on from [Daniel Kamil Kozar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-can-i-calculate-time-elapsed-in-a-bash-script/8903280#8903280), to show hours/minutes/seconds:

```
echo "Duration: $(($DIFF / 3600 )) hours $((($DIFF % 3600) / 60)) minutes $(($DIFF % 60)) seconds"
```

So the full script would be:

```
date1=$(date +"%s")
date2=$(date +"%s")
DIFF=$(($date2-$date1))
echo "Duration: $(($DIFF / 3600 )) hours $((($DIFF % 3600) / 60)) minutes $(($DIFF % 60)) seconds"
```

Comment: Many solutions don't work for time intervals that exceed 86399 seconds. This one has no such limitation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's some magic:

```
time1=14:30
time2=$( date +%H:%M ) # 16:00
diff=$(  echo "$time2 - $time1"  | sed 's%:%+(1/60)*%g' | bc -l )
echo $diff hours
# outputs 1.5 hours
```

[`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) replaces a `:` with a formula to convert to 1/60. Then the time calculation that is made by [`bc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)).

Answer (score 7):

As of *date* ([GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities)) 7.4, you can now use `-d` to do arithmetic:

```
$ date -d -30days

Sat Jun 28 13:36:35 UTC 2014

$ date -d tomorrow

Tue Jul 29 13:40:55 UTC 2014
```

The units you can use are days, years, months, hours, minutes, and seconds :

```
$ date -d tomorrow+2days-10minutes

Thu Jul 31 13:33:02 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using only the `date` commands capabilities using "ago", and not using a second variable to store the finish time:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save the current time
start_time=$( date +%s.%N )

# Tested program
sleep 1

# The current time after the program has finished
# minus the time when we started, in seconds.nanoseconds
elapsed_time=$( date +%s.%N --date="$start_time seconds ago" )

echo elapsed_time: $elapsed_time
```

This gives:

```
$ ./time_elapsed.sh

elapsed_time: 1.002257120
```

Comment: You can also add a `printf` to format to two decimal places. Eg: % echo elapsed: $(printf '%.2f' ${elapsed_time})s

Answer (score 3):

```
% start=$(date +%s)
% echo "Diff: $(date -d @$(($(date +%s)-$start)) +"%M minutes %S seconds")"
Diff: 00 minutes 11 seconds
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what this answer does that the other answers don't do.

Comment: It lets you easily output the duration in any format allowed by `date`.

Answer (score 3):

Or wrap it up a bit

```
alias timerstart='starttime=$(date +"%s")'
alias timerstop='echo seconds=$(($(date +"%s")-$starttime))'
```

Then this works.

```
timerstart; sleep 2; timerstop
seconds=2
```

Answer (score 3):

`date` can give you the difference and format it for you (OS X options shown)

```
date -ujf%s $(($(date -jf%T "10:36:10" +%s) - $(date -jf%T "10:33:56" +%s))) +%T
# 00:02:14

date -ujf%s $(($(date -jf%T "10:36:10" +%s) - $(date -jf%T "10:33:56" +%s))) \
    +'%-Hh %-Mm %-Ss'
# 0h 2m 14s
```

Some string processing can remove those empty values

```
date -ujf%s $(($(date -jf%T "10:36:10" +%s) - $(date -jf%T "10:33:56" +%s))) \
    +'%-Hh %-Mm %-Ss' | sed "s/[[:<:]]0[hms] *//g"
# 2m 14s
```

This won't work if you place the earlier time first. If you need to handle that, change `$(($(date ...) - $(date ...)))` to `$(echo $(date ...) - $(date ...) | bc | tr -d -)`

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

START_TIME=$(date +%s)

sleep 4

echo "Total time elapsed: $(date -ud "@$(($(date +%s) - $START_TIME))" +%T) (HH:MM:SS)"
```

```
$ ./total_time_elapsed.sh 
Total time elapsed: 00:00:04 (HH:MM:SS)
```

Answer (score 3):

Define this function (say, in [~/.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)):

```
time::clock() {
    [ -z "$ts" ]&&{ ts=`date +%s%N`;return;}||te=`date +%s%N`
    printf "%6.4f" $(echo $((te-ts))/1000000000 | bc -l)
    unset ts te
}
```

Now you can measure execution time of parts of your scripts:

```
$ cat script.sh
# ... code ...
time::clock
sleep 0.5
echo "Total time: ${time::clock}"
# ... more code ...

$ ./script.sh
Total time: 0.5060
```

It is very useful to find execution bottlenecks.

Comment: awesome - with sub-second accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing [nisetama's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-can-i-calculate-time-elapsed-in-a-bash-script/43289564#43289564) using GNU date ([Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr)):

```
start=`date`
# <processing code>
stop=`date`
duration=`date -ud@$(($(date -ud"$stop" +%s)-$(date -ud"$start" +%s))) +%T`

echo $start
echo $stop
echo $duration
```

yielding:

```
Wed Feb 7 12:31:16 CST 2018
Wed Feb 7 12:32:25 CST 2018
00:01:09
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a time difference script for use with [`mencoder`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mencoder) (its `--endpos` is relative), and my solution is to call a Python script:

```
$ ./timediff.py 1:10:15 2:12:44
1:02:29
```

Fractions of seconds are also supported:

```
$ echo "diff is `./timediff.py 10:51.6 12:44` (in hh:mm:ss format)"
diff is 0:01:52.4 (in hh:mm:ss format)
```

And it can tell you that the difference between 200 and 120 is 1h 20m:

```
$ ./timediff.py 120:0 200:0
1:20:0
```

And it can convert any (probably fractional) number of seconds or minutes or hours to hh:mm:ss:

```
$ ./timediff.py 0 3600
1:00:0

$ ./timediff.py 0 3.25:0:0
3:15:0
```

*timediff.py:*

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def x60(h, m):
    return 60*float(h) + float(m)

def seconds(time):
    try:
       h, m, s = time.split(':')
       return x60(x60(h, m), s)
    except ValueError:
       try:
          m, s = time.split(':')
          return x60(m, s)
       except ValueError:
          return float(time)

def difftime(start, end):
    d = seconds(end) - seconds(start)
    print '%d:%02d:%s' % (d/3600,d/60%60,('%02f' % (d%60)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   difftime(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

With [GNU Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Units):

```
units
```

Output:

```
2411 units, 71 prefixes, 33 nonlinear units
You have: (10hr+36min+10s)-(10hr+33min+56s)
You want: s
    * 134
    / 0.0074626866
You have: (10hr+36min+10s)-(10hr+33min+56s)
You want: min
    * 2.2333333
    / 0.44776119
```

Comment: Hidden list (annotated) [of GNU software](https://www.gnu.org/manual/blurbs.html).

Answer (score 0):

I came across it today while working on a script that would take dates and times from a log file and compute the delta. The script below is certainly overkill, and I highly recommend checking my logic and maths.

```
#!/bin/bash

dTime=""
tmp=""

#firstEntry="$(head -n 1 "$LOG" | sed 's/.*] \([0-9: -]\+\).*/\1/')"
firstEntry="2013-01-16 01:56:37"
#lastEntry="$(tac "$LOG" | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*] \([0-9: -]\+\).*/\1/')"
lastEntry="2014-09-17 18:24:02"

# I like to make the variables easier to parse
firstEntry="${firstEntry//-/ }"
lastEntry="${lastEntry//-/ }"
firstEntry="${firstEntry//:/ }"
lastEntry="${lastEntry//:/ }"

# Remove the following lines in production
echo "$lastEntry"
echo "$firstEntry"

# Compute days in last entry
for i in `seq 1 $(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $2}')`; do {
  case "$i" in
   1|3|5|7|8|10|12 )
    dTime=$(($dTime+31))
    ;;
   4|6|9|11 )
    dTime=$(($dTime+30))
    ;;
   2 )
    dTime=$(($dTime+28))
    ;;
  esac
} done

# Do leap year calculations for all years between first and last entry
for i in `seq $(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $1}') $(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $1}')`; do {
  if [ $(($i%4)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($i%100)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($i%400)) -eq 0 ]; then {
    if [ "$i" = "$(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $1}')" ] && [ $(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $2}') -lt 2 ]; then {
      dTime=$(($dTime+1))
    } elif [ $(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $2}') -eq 2 ] && [ $(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $3}') -lt 29 ]; then {
      dTime=$(($dTime+1))
    } fi
  } elif [ $(($i%4)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($i%100)) -ne 0 ]; then {
    if [ "$i" = "$(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $1}')" ] && [ $(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $2}') -gt 2 ]; then {
      dTime=$(($dTime+1))
    } elif [ $(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $2}') -eq 2 ] && [ $(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $3}') -ne 29 ]; then {
      dTime=$(($dTime+1))
    } fi
  } fi
} done

# Subtract days in first entry
for i in `seq 1 $(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $2}')`; do {
  case "$i" in
   1|3|5|7|8|10|12 )
    dTime=$(($dTime-31))
    ;;
   4|6|9|11 )
    dTime=$(($dTime-30))
    ;;
   2 )
    dTime=$(($dTime-28))
    ;;
  esac
} done

dTime=$(($dTime+$(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $3}')-$(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $3}')))

# The above gives number of days for sample. Now
# we need hours, minutes, and seconds
# As a bit of hackery I just put the stuff
# in the best order for use in a for loop
dTime="$(($(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $6}')-$(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $6}'))) $(($(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $5}')-$(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $5}'))) $(($(echo $lastEntry|awk '{print $4}')-$(echo $firstEntry|awk '{print $4}'))) $dTime"
tmp=1
for i in $dTime; do {
  if [ $i -lt 0 ]; then {
    case "$tmp" in
     1 )
      tmp="$(($(echo $dTime|awk '{print $1}')+60)) $(($(echo $dTime|awk '{print $2}')-1))"
      dTime="$tmp $(echo $dTime|awk '{print $3" "$4}')"
      tmp=1
      ;;
     2 )
      tmp="$(($(echo $dTime|awk '{print $2}')+60)) $(($(echo $dTime|awk '{print $3}')-1))"
      dTime="$(echo $dTime|awk '{print $1}') $tmp $(echo $dTime|awk '{print $4}')"
      tmp=2
      ;;
     3 )
      tmp="$(($(echo $dTime|awk '{print $3}')+24)) $(($(echo $dTime|awk '{print $4}')-1))"
      dTime="$(echo $dTime|awk '{print $1" "$2}') $tmp"
      tmp=3
      ;;
    esac
  } fi
  tmp=$(($tmp+1))
} done

echo "The sample time is $(echo $dTime|awk '{print $4}') days, $(echo $dTime|awk '{print $3}') hours, $(echo $dTime|awk '{print $2}') minutes, and $(echo $dTime|awk '{print $1}') seconds."
```

You will get output as follows.

```
2012 10 16 01 56 37
2014 09 17 18 24 02
The sample time is 700 days, 16 hours, 27 minutes, and 25 seconds.
```

I modified the script a bit to make it standalone (i.e., just set variable values), but maybe the general idea comes across as well. You'd might want some additional error checking for negative values.

Comment: Gee, a lot of work!!. Please look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24996647/2350426

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the time differential calculated, and they're shorter than 1 day, here's a really fringe use case of [`bc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) to kinda-sorta format the output into a

- `HH MM SS.xxxx`

`24-hour` format, keeping in mind that the digits to right of decimal point are printed in ***`base 60`***

> ```
> jot -w 'obase = 60; %.3f' - 1.3219567 300 73.6543211 | bc
> ```

```
       01.19 19
    01 14.58 33
    02 28.37 51
    03 42.17 06  # 3 mins 42 secs 
    04 55.56 20  
          ...
          ...
 19 38 10.54 32  # 19 hrs 38 mins 10 secs 
                 #
                 # (or 7:38pm, if it's representing absolute time)
```

But it's definitely a quick-n-dirty way to get a ballpark figure.

Answer (score -2):

Here's my Bash implementation (with bits taken from other Stack Overflow answers ;-)

```
function countTimeDiff() {
    timeA=$1 # 09:59:35
    timeB=$2 # 17:32:55

    # feeding variables by using read and splitting with IFS
    IFS=: read ah am as <<< "$timeA"
    IFS=: read bh bm bs <<< "$timeB"

    # Convert hours to minutes.
    # The 10# is there to avoid errors with leading zeros
    # by telling bash that we use base 10
    secondsA=$((10#$ah*60*60 + 10#$am*60 + 10#$as))
    secondsB=$((10#$bh*60*60 + 10#$bm*60 + 10#$bs))
    DIFF_SEC=$((secondsB - secondsA))
    echo "The difference is $DIFF_SEC seconds.";

    SEC=$(($DIFF_SEC%60))
    MIN=$((($DIFF_SEC-$SEC)%3600/60))
    HRS=$((($DIFF_SEC-$MIN*60)/3600))
    TIME_DIFF="$HRS:$MIN:$SEC";
    echo $TIME_DIFF;
}

$ countTimeDiff 2:15:55 2:55:16
The difference is 2361 seconds.
0:39:21
```

It was not tested and may be buggy.