# how to calculate the total minutes between two dates?

Tags: shell, unix

Can anyone help me to calculate the total minutes between below two dates.

date1= 2016-07-02 06:20:00

date2= 2016-07-04 15:00:00

the output should be in number for example the date diff is only 5 hours means i need the output like 5*60=300 minutes.

Thanks,
AAA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309032/bash-script-difference-in-minutes-between-two-times

Comment: Thanks PS. Its working fine which you redirected.
sh-4.3$ #! /bin/bash   
sh-4.3$ currentdate=$(date -u +%s -d '2007-09-01 17:30:24')
sh-4.3$ targetdate=$(date -u +%s -d '2007-12-25  12:30:00')
sh-4.3$ minutes=$(( ($targetdate - $currentdate) / 60 ))                                                                                                      
sh-4.3$ echo $minutes                                                                                                                                         
165299
Thanks a lot to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $((($(date -ud "$date2" +'%s') - $(date -ud "$date1" +'%s'))/60)) minutes`

Comment: I have tried that but i am getting below error

sh-4.3$ dtae1="2016-07-02 06:20:00" 
sh-4.3$ dtae2="2016-07-15 04:27:00" 
sh-4.3$ echo $((($(date -ud "$dtae2"+'%s')- $(date -ud "$dtae1"+'%s'))/60)) minutes                                                                 
date: invalid date '2016-07-15 04:27:00+%s'                                                                                                                   
date: invalid date '2016-07-02 06:20:00+%s'  
sh: (- )/60: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")/60")

Comment: Thanks Sorin. Its working fine now . sh-4.3$ #! /bin/bash sh-4.3$ currentdate=$(date -u +%s -d '2007-09-01 17:30:24') sh-4.3$ targetdate=$(date -u +%s -d '2007-12-25 12:30:00') sh-4.3$ minutes=$(( ($targetdate - $currentdate) / 60 )) sh-4.3$ echo $minutes 165299 Thanks a lot to all