# How to Set UNIX HH:MM:SS to a Date time to calculate time difference

Tags: bash, unix, time

I want to calculate the difference in time by passing in a string `HH:MM` value to set the time and calculating the difference between this and the current system time.

I'm aware of `date --set="2013-07-10"+%T` (or something like this). But I cannot figure out how to set the time part to be the string `HH:MM` value that I pass in and leave the data as the current date. Then, to calculate I was trying to use the below which changes it into a timestamp value; which I found from another user:

```
mydate=??
date1=$($mydate +"%s")  #my set date/time here
date2=$(date +"%s")
diff=$(($date2-$date1))
echo "$(($diff / 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60))"
```

Comment: refer this link



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date -d hh:mm` to create a new date with a specified time.

Example:

```
$ date -d 11:15
Wed Jul 10 11:15:00 BST 2013
```

Using this, you can write the following script:

```
time=11:15

now=$(date +%s)
other=$(date -d $time +%s)
diff=$((other-now))
echo "$((diff / 60)) minutes and $((diff % 60)) seconds"
```

Comment: Great, thanks for fast response.  If I had to do a diff where the Passed in time is past midnight, day+1..  and time at 02:00, would this be straight forward?

Comment: A bare time is interpreted as belonging to the current day. You'll need to set `time` to distinguish between the time tomorrow and the time today: `time="tomorrow 11:15"`.