# Calculation of hours between two time stamp using unix script

Tags: unix, scripting

I have a requirement to calculate hours between two time stamp,

Example:
Date1 : 2016-02-24 08:30:10
Date2 : 2016-02-26 11:25:10

The script should consider the date and time as well while calculating hours.

please provide the information....

Comment: The tone of this question seems a little bit demanding. That's probably not your intention. Consider rewording the last sentence.

Comment: Have a look at this link. Which scripting language you are using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script/24996647#24996647

Comment: If you have GNU date, use `date -d "$date" '+%s`, and do a little arithmetic.