# Calculate time (h:m:s or m:s) difference in bash

Tags: bash, time, diff

I want to display the duration of a command in my script. Depeding the duration I want somethng like this: `12 minutes 04 seconds` or `01 hours 15 minutes 02 seconds`. Always with a leading zero.

I tried different things I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script), but didn't get the result.

BTW: that's my first try in the bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE1=$(date +%s)  
# ... your commands 
DATE2=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(awk -vdate1=$DATE1 -vdate2=$DATE2 'BEGIN{print strftime("%H hour %M minutes %S seconds",date2-date1,1)}')
echo $DIFF
```

Time is converted to seconds and stored in variables DATE1 and DATE2
 pre-condition DATE2 > DATE1

```
DATE1=$(date +%s)  
# ... your commands 
DATE2=$(date +%s)
```

*strftime* is used to get time-diff in seconds and formatted
1 is passed as 3rd argument as UTC Flag

```
strftime("%H hour %M minutes %S seconds",date2-date1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried different versions and this one is great for me:

`
        start_time=$(date +"%s")

        # do my commands

        end_time=$(date +"%s")
        duration=$(($end_time-$start_time))
        hours=$(printf '%02d' "$(($duration /3600 ))")
        minutes=$(printf '%02d' "$((($duration % 3600) / 60))")
        seconds=$(printf '%02d' "$(($duration % 60))")
        if [ $hours -eq 0 ]
        then
                com_time=$(printf "$minutes:$seconds minutes")
        else
                com_time=$(printf "$hours:$minutes hours")
        fi
´

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `time` executable (not the bash builtin because the external program features the format option `-f` and delivers the time as `[hours:]minutes:seconds` and I am not in the mood right now to wait an hour to find out how the builtin shows us the hours :) ) and awk like this (using the example `sleep 2`):

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%E" sleep 2 2> >( 
   awk -F : ' 
    { if(FN>2) printf("%02d hours %02d minutes %02d seconds\n", $1, $2, $3)
      else printf("%02d minutes %02d seconds\n", $1, $2) 
    }' 
)
```

Here we use `/usr/bin/time` with its `-f` option. Then we pipe the output of stderr into `awk` splitting the string at `:`. (time writes to stderr, thus we need the `2>` to redirect stderr into the `>( awk ... )` filter.

The awk filter decides on the number of fields in `NF` what `printf` statement it is using.

Comment: That sounds cool. My command to check the time is multible lines long. In your example only `sleep 2`.

How can I add my command in ist own lines?

Comment: @Gurkenglas: first idea: put your commands into a script of its own and time that script; second idea: use Chets solution. I tried to put `cmd1; cmd2` into the sleeps place and `(cmd1; cmd2)`; nothing worked.