# Subtract date & time from current date & time in bash

Tags: bash

Lets say I have below two variables.

```
!#/bin/bash
MEMFILE=lock-file
date +%s > $MEMFILE
sleep 130
UPTIME= `date +%s`
```

I want to take the output of ( $UPTIME - $MEMFILE) in minutes and seconds.

Eg:

```
 "Total downtime was 2 minutes and 5 seconds"
```

Comment: All these came at single line. i'm sorry. I didnt know how it can be code properly in this forum. since i'm new.

Comment: You should indent the code with 4 leading spaces in the line. Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script Seen this?

Comment: I don't know that you really want to do ([you want to do X, you think that to do X you need Y, so you ask a question about Y](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)), but using the `SECONDS` variable might help you: `SECONDS=0; sleep 130; uptime=$SECONDS; echo "Total downtime was $((uptime/60)) minutes and $((uptime%60)) seconds"`. The `SECONDS=0` line is to reset the `SECONDS` counter: it's then incremented by one every second. See [what the manual says about `SECONDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-SECONDS).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

---

Subtracting times obtained from `date`:

```
#!/bin/bash

startdate=$(date +%s)
sleep 130
enddate=$(date +%s)
timetaken=$((enddate-startdate))
printf 'Total downtime was %d minutes and %d seconds\n' "$((timetaken/60))" "$((timetaken%60))"
```

The same without the external process `date` (since Bash 4.2):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf -v startdate '%(%s)T' -1
sleep 130
printf -v enddate '%(%s)T' -1
timetaken=$((enddate-startdate))
printf 'Total downtime was %d minutes and %d seconds\n' "$((timetaken/60))" "$((timetaken%60))"
```

The subtraction of times and computing the minutes and seconds are done using [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).

---

Using [Bash's `SECONDS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-SECONDS) (probably the best for you):

```
#!/bin/bash

SECONDS=0 # reset the SECONDS variable
sleep 130
timetaken=$SECONDS
printf 'Total downtime was %d minutes and %d seconds\n' "$((timetaken/60))" "$((timetaken%60))"
```

After being set to an integer value the special variable `SECONDS` is incremented each second.

---

Using Bash's [`time`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-time) keyword with an appropriate [`TIMEFORMAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-TIMEFORMAT) (here, we won't be able to write the elapsed time as *MM minutes and SS seconds*; it'll be shown in the form of `MmSs`, i.e., *Total downtime was 2m10s*).

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEFORMAT='Total downtime was %0lR'

time {
    # do your stuff in this block
    sleep 130
}
```

---

Note that the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script) already contains a lot of material.