# Bash assign floating point result to a variable

Tags: bash

I need to make a simple floating point operation: 
I tried to use both BC and awk with no success...

```
remainingTime=$(((duration/numOfRevisions)*remainingRevision))
echo  "$(($remainingTime / 60)) minutes and $(($remainingTime % 60)) seconds remaining."
```

All variables are integer numbers (duration is the number of seconds) 
My problem is to calculate the variable remaining time, so as to use print formatted in the second line.

my attempt in `Awk`

```
remainingTime=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\",${duration}/${numOfRevisions}*${remainingRevision}}‌​"
```

Comment: `bash` only supports integer arithmetic. If you want floating point, you have to do it in a language like `awk` or `bc`.

Comment: **I tried to use both BC and awk with no success** I don't see where you try to do this.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts with `bc` and `awk`

Comment: @Barmar, This is the awk command I tried 

remainingTime=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\",${duration}/${numOfRevisions}*${remainingRevision}}")

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` after the `awk` command. Other than that, it works for me.

Comment: @Inian His awk code is inside double quotes, so `bash` will expand the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` doesn't support floating point operations. With `bc` you need to use `bc --mathlib` if you want to use floating point values:

```
bc --mathlib <<< "(${duration}/${numberOfRevisions})*${remainingRevision}"
```

Comment: I tried to use it but I get an error, it seems the variable "remainingTime" cannot formatted anymore

     remainingTime=$(bc -l <<< "(${duration}/${numberOfRevisions})*${remainingRevision}")
     echo  "$(($remainingTime / 60)) minutes and $(($remainingTime % 60)) seconds remaining."

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem combining @Barmar solution with another solution 
[How to calculate time difference in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script) 
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

The resulting  command is :

```
remainingTime=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\",${duration}/${revisionCounter}*${remainingRevision}}‌​")
remainingTime=${remainingTime%.*}
echo  "$(($remainingTime / 60)) minutes and $(($remainingTime % 60)) seconds remaining."
```