# Timestamp Subtraction Using Bash-Utils

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hey I am trying to calculate the difference between time stamp of a file in which I **always want to subtract the last the fields** using **bash/bash-utils**. This is how the file looks

`14:11:56.953700000,172.20.10.1
14:25:49.233263000,172.20.10.1`

Now the issue is that I want to lose that huge number and IP from the calculation.

I can put them in csv or any data file needed.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "subtract the last fields", although you could do `awk -F'.' '{print $1}'` to show only the time without nanoseconds.

Comment: @I'L'I as in subtracting those two time stamps to tell what's the difference between both on them in minutes

Comment: Use something like that awk command to get the part of the string you want, then [review this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script). The question deals with the exact same format as you want...

Comment: @Coding_Karma, please always add your efforts in your post too what you have put in order to solve your problem. Also by seeing your profile seems like you hardly select any answer as correct, so please always do so(select any one of the answer as correct one) to close the thread completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F'[.,]' '
FNR==1{
  split($1,time,":");
  sec=time[1] * 3600+time[2]*60+time[3]}
FNR==2{
  split($1,time1,":");
  sec1=time1[1] * 3600+time1[2]*60+time1[3];
  seconds=(sec1-sec)%60;
  min=sprintf("%d",(sec1-sec)/60);
  printf("%s %s\n",min" min",seconds" sec")
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
13 min 53 sec
```