# bash script - how to get the time difference (in hour:minute:seconds) between two unix-timestamps

Tags: bash, unix-timestamp

I need to get the time difference between two unix-timestamps in hour, minute, and seconds. I can get the different in minutes and seconds correctly but the hour is always wrong.

I have two unix-timestamps and I subtract to get the difference.

1595455100 - 1595452147 = 2953
(That's the time difference between 2:09:07pm and 2:58:20pm on the same day)

Then I do `date -d @2953 +'%I:%M:%S'`

I get `04:49:13` but I expect to get `0:49:13`

I'd also tried `date -d @2953 +'%H:%M:%S'` and `date -d @2953 +'%T'` and get `16:49:13`. I've also checked differences greater than an hour, the difference in minute and seconds is still correct but the hour is still wrong.

I don't understand the Hour format and appreciate any help.

Comment: You are getting the local time. Put `-u` option to the `date` command.

Comment: Using `date` to print a time interval won't work when the time interval is longer than 24 hours. Watch what happens when you use 222953 and then 992953.

Comment: So long as you need only hours, minutes, and seconds, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22141974/1707353) will work.

Comment: @JeffHolt Thanks! That worked for what I needed. I am still confused why `date` doesn't work for the hour. The two timestamps I gave above were in the same 24 hour interval, 0hrs 49min and 13 secs apart. I tried also comparing two timestamps over a month apart and again minute and seconds were correct but hour was not.

Comment: tshiono's comment says it all. Your local timezone is not UTC and so `date` adds the time between UTC and your local timezone to the intuitive difference in the value you give it. It's not unreasonable to expect the `date` command to act that way. It was never intended to do what you are wanting.

Comment: Try `TZ=UTC0 date -d @86399 +%H:%M:%S` and then try `TZ=UTC0 date -d @86400 +%H:%M:%S` to see tshiono's point play out wrt to my comments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need `date` for this conversion. You can use integer math and `printf` for fun and profit.

```sh
start=1595452147
end=1595455100
s=$((end - start))
time=$(printf %02d:%02d:%02d $((s / 3600)) $((s / 60 % 60)) $((s % 60)))
echo $time
```

There may be a way to do it with `date` too, but the above should work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for wrong answer is because the timestamp @0 is not an absolute 0 of some kind. It is the fixed datetime at:

```bash
date -d@0 -u
# Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

You could do:

```bash
eval echo `date -d @$(($ts1 - $ts2)) -u +'$((%d - 01)) days, %H:%M:%Ss'`
# 0 days, 00:09:20s
```

as long as number of days is less than 31